# Return Observer.create Not returning and code next to it not working using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

Well i am pretty much new to reactive programming. problem is, I have a function(A) which returns an object , now I have another function(B) which subscribes returning object from function A and I make function B also as returning an other object in that subscribe, now this whole return this is not work. I have no idea why is happening.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
**Function A**

```
func getClassById(classId: Int) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return Observable.create{[weak self] observer -> Disposable in            Alamofire.request("URL", method:.get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self!.getRequestHeader())
            .validate()
            .responseJSON{ response in
                switch response.result {
                    do {
                        let assingnedClass = try JSONDecoder().decode(AssignedClassModel.self, from: data)
                        observer.onNext(true)
                    } catch {
                        observer.onError(error)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

**Function B**

```
func getAssignedClassData(classId: Int) -> Observable<[StudentModel]>  { 
    return Observable.create{[weak self] observer -> Disposable in // from here code is not going further.
    APIService.singelton
        .getClassById(classId: classId)
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] assingnedClass in
            let studentsData = Array(Database.singleton.fetchStudents(byCLassId: classId))
            print(studentsData)
            observer.onNext(studentsData)
            }, onError: { error in
                print(error)
        }).disposed(by: self!.disposeBag)
        return Disposables.create()
        }
}
```

**Function B2**

```
    func getAssignedClassData(classId: Int) -> Observable<[StudentModel]>  {
        return APIService.singelton
            .getClassById(classId: classId)
            .do(onError: { error in
                print(error)
            })
            .map({ [weak self] assingnedClass in
                return Array(Database.singleton.fetchStudents(byCLassId: classId))
// this code will not be triggered as it is after return. 
                let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC") as? TabBarViewController
                let transition = CATransition()
                transition.duration = 0.5
                transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
                transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
                self?.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

            })
    }
```

Comment: 1. I think you have a pair of compilation errors in function A. 2. Why do you need assignedClass? You don't use it in Function B as I see. 3. How do you use getAssignedClassData (Function B). Could you provide a sample of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no Observable creation needed in Function B. If you want to transform one observable to another you can use [`map` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html).
2. There is an error handling trouble in Function B. Error will be caught, but Observable will never be completed. In my example I used just side effect for printing error, so error will be propagated and `map` will not run. There are some strategies for [error handling in RxSwift](http://mudox.github.io/post/rxswift-operators---error-handling/).
3. Function B doesn't need `asObservable`.
4. The result of Function A (`assingnedClass`) is not used. Probably the real code was simplified.
5. There is no `observer.onCompleted()` after `observer.onNext()` in Function A. Your observable will not be completed and disposed at time.

Here is my example:

```
class StudentService {
    ...
    func getAssignedClassData(classId: Int) -> Observable<[StudentModel]> {
        return APIService.singelton
            .getClassById(classId: classId)
            .do(onError: { error in
                print(error)
            })
            .map { _ in Array(Database.singelton.fetchStudents(byCLassId: classId)) }
    }
}

class SomeController: UIViewController {
    ...
    func fetchStudentsAndPushViewController() {
        studentService
            .getAssignedClassData(classId: classId)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
                let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarVC") as? TabBarViewController
                let transition = CATransition()
                transition.duration = 0.5
                transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
                transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
                self?.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
            })
            .disposed(by: self!.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

BTW. You can try [RxAlamofire](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxAlamofire) for you `APIService` so you won't need to wrap the request into Observable by yourself.

Comment: Hi thanks for response. I have changed **Function A** return type to _bool_ and now my **Function B** look likes, but it has issues also. 
`func getAssignedClassData(classId: Int) -> Observable<[StudentModel]>  {
        print("GOES HERE")
        APIService.singelton
            .getClassById(classId: classId)
            .do(onError: { error in
                print(error)
            })
        .map({[weak self ] value in
            return Array(Database.singleton.fetchStudents(byCLassId: classId))
        })
    }`

Comment: Plus this warning is popping up **Result of call to 'map' is unused** and error is **Missing return in a function expected to return 'Observable<[StudentModel]>'**

Comment: I have used another way for this and updated my answer look for the code Function B2

Comment: Why have you removed `return`? So you get compilation error.

Comment: but do what I return here ? it needs `Observable<[StudentModel]>` where do I get it here..

Comment: By using `map` function you transform one observable to another. So map function returns observable but of another type.

Comment: Please try to understand the article I sent you in my answer.

Comment: did you looked at **Function B2** code too. it gives me same error if i remove return from last bracket.

Comment: as what I understand, if you use observable.just or map you are returning a value for its subscriber, then why need here to return again. I don't get it .

Comment: Okay I did and now I know what map does. plus how to handle error next. but I have still one confusion, map function transform the emitted value to other type right, but in my case my emitted value is just a bool. but I want to further emit [StudentModel]. i was using bool to check if data is loaded in DB nothing much.

Comment: You created an Observable that emits empty array one time - nothing more.

Comment: You are already creating Observable in `getClassById`. Just transform it in `getAssignedClassData` like in my example. Or probably rethink whole idea.

Comment: What do you get when using my example without changes?

Comment: okay I tell you what I am doing ,
what i want is , I am using MVVM, and RxSwift,
then i have a DB for students `StudentModel` which i get from server which I call from getting some value from a QR code.,
QR Code > `getAssignedClassData` (DB updates here) > `getClassById` (here I want an observer of `StudentModel`) > now I subscribe from `getClassById` the `[StudentModel]` and pass to `CollectionView` using DataBinding.
what I want is to observe StudentModel if it changes after calling Api function and loads the current Data. not the previously stored data.

Comment: i get this error when I implement your code **Missing return in a function expected to return 'Observable<[StudentModel]>'**

Comment: But there is `return` in my implementation! ) Give me your complete code please.

Comment: sorry my bad, i was editing wrong function, yes it does work , but i want to push another viewController too, but unable because of return statement.

Comment: updated my **Function B2** code with latest one . check that please.

Comment: I would like not to mix business and UI logic especially not in UI thread.

Comment: but my business logic is not even here, so does the UI logic. I didn't understand why you say that.

Comment: I hope I've made complete answer to your question now? ))

Comment: yes it did worked thank you for that :) you are amazing